# Python regular expression return positions of string inside the parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

Using regular expression I'm trying to get the positions of string inside the parenthesis.

For example I want to get the position of "Home Depot" ;

```
sent = "Sales to two of the segment's customers, The Home Depot and Lowe's Home Improvement Warehouse, accounted for greater than 10% of the Corporation's consolidated sales for 2004, 2003, and 2002."

regex_ = re.compile("Sales to two of the segment's customers, The (Home Depot)
```

However,

```
regex_.search(sent).span()
```

returns `(0, 55)` not `(45, 55)`

Since, there could be multiple "home depot" in sent, I am not able to use `re.search('Home Depot', sent).span()` which might not return the exact position of Home Depot I am looking for.

Comment: Why is the string hard-coded into the regex? That doesn't make much sense

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh.. actually all I tried to know was finding out where the word 'Home Depot'  located when I know what strings are behind it. The first thing came up to my mind was Regex, hence I gave it a shot. Is there any way that you can recommend for me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the position of the text in parentheses, you need to specify that you're matching the first group as an argument to `span()`:

```
sent = "Sales to two of the segment's customers, The Home Depot and Lowe's Home Improvement Warehouse, accounted for greater than 10% of the Corporation's consolidated sales for 2004, 2003, and 2002."

regex_ = re.compile("Sales to two of the segment's customers, The (Home Depot)

regex_.search(sent).span(1)
```

See the python documentation on [match objects and `span`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookbehind:

```
sent = "Sales to two of the segment's customers, The Home Depot and Lowe's Home Improvement Warehouse, accounted for greater than 10% of the Corporation's consolidated sales for 2004, 2003, and 2002."
regex_ = re.compile(r"(?<=Sales to two of the segment's customers, The )Home Depot")
print(regex_.search(sent).span())
```

**Output:**

```
(45, 55)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct. But you are asking for the position for the whole match and not for the submatch. To get the position of the first submatch, use `span(1)`

```
>>> regex_ = re.compile("Sales to two of the segment's customers, The (Home Depot)")
>>> regex_.search(sent).span(1)
(45, 55)
```